# Get Channel entries using custom filed type value

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields

Is there a way to return channel entries based on a custom field type value? I have set up a custom field type and I want to be able to return channel entries that just a have a specific value for that field. Is that possible?

Oh, and just to make it more complicated I can't use the `search:field_name=` parameter because:

1. The custom fieldtype I need to search is a P&T Dropdown
2. I actually need to also return any results that match a specific `author_id=` value in the same channel entry results
3. I really need to query multiple custom fields across multiple channels

So what a I really need is a `OR` type query using a custom field as a parameter. I thought about creating a custom query or even making a quick plug-in, but the channel entries table along with trying to query custom field data is so convoluted. It's seriously a complete nightmare.

I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good candidate for the [**Channel Query**](https://github.com/expressodev/channel_query) plugin. It has all of the features of `{exp:channel:entries}`, with the flexibility of the Query module.

```
{exp:channel_query 
    sql="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE /* your custom query here */"
}
    <!-- all channel entries variables can be used here -->
{/exp:channel_query}
```

Your custom query gets the entry_id's that match your criteria. Then, because you've got all the parameters and variables that come with the [channel:entries tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html), there should be no further querying for entries-related data needed. Just template as usual, as if you are using the native channel:entries tag.